# What is the purpose of event parameter kind = "calendar#event". in google calendar API

Tags: android-calendar, google-calendar-api

What is the purpose of event parameter

> kind = "calendar#event"

. in `google calendar API`?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn6Lo.png)

Reference link - >

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Type of the collection ("calendar#events").

It tells what resource type you are using base on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/).

For example:

You are getting data from calendar events so the `"kind"` will be

```
 {
  "kind": "calendar#events",
  "etag": "\"00000000000000000\"",
  "summary": "someon@something.com",
  "updated": "2098-09-16T21:11:56.805Z",
  "timeZone": "Asia/Manila",
  "accessRole": "owner",
  "defaultReminders": [
   {
    "method": "popup",
    "minutes": 10
   }
  ]
 {...}
}
```

Another example is to get data from calendar colors

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#colors",
  "updated": "2012-02-14T00:00:00.000Z",
  "calendar": {
   "1": {
    "background": "#FFFFFF",
    "foreground": "#AAAAAA"
   },
  {...}
 }
}
```

Calendar List for the last example,

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendarList",
 "etag": "\"p324cv3ddpuldc0g\"",
 "nextSyncToken": "CIjPja3PqtYCEhNhbWFnbmFiZUBnb29nbGUuY29t",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry",
   "etag": "\"00000000000000000\"",
   "id": "AAAAABBBB_BBBB_AAA@group.calendar.something.com",
   "summary": "My summary",
   "timeZone": "UTC",
   "colorId": "1",
   "backgroundColor": "0000001",
   "foregroundColor": "#5555555",
   "selected": true,
   "accessRole": "owner",
   "defaultReminders": []
  },
 {...}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can i share the secondary calendar with some one and get list of persons with whom i shared this secondary calendar?Please guide i didn't get any reference from google calendar api.

Answer (score 1):

It is just informative Resource Identifier.